# Incremental level 1 backup with no Incremental level 0?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I have done the following steps:

1. Backed up database with **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0**
2. Delete **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0** backup without telling controlfile. So deleted it by hand. And did not make crosscheck.
3. Backed up database with **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1**(without making crosscheck).  How surprising it may be, log showed me that **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1** was successfully  done.

Note, I have no **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0** backup, but controlfile doesn't know it. I have just **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1**.

I tried to restore database with this backup but of course couldn't. It was telling me that no backup of datafile 1-5 found...

If controlfile had known about EXPIRED backups , then **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1** backup first would do **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0** and after-that **INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1**.

How to avoid this situation. Do I have to use chrosscheck in my backup script? Or set recovery window in RMAN?

I have Oracle 11g database. 
Backup is taken by Netbackup Server. So Netbackup deletes backups itself by its retention.
RMAN retention policy is configured to REDUNDANCY 2.

Please, Advice me.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard to test.  Do a `CROSSCHECK` and then see if it allows you to create an incremental 1 backup when it knows the 0 doesn't exist.

Comment: @LeighRiffel I have already tested and after crosscheck it made inc 0 backup first and then inc 1. (without crosschek it makes inc 1 just)
I just wonder to know how you do when using Netbackup as backup server. Do you use crosscheck in backup script? I was not using crosscheck but after founding that inc 1 may be done with no errors even u don't have inc 0 which means that you are not able to restore database because u don't have all backups AND you don't know about this! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you want to prevent a level 1 from being created without a corresponding level 0 being available, then you need to do a crosscheck in the script so RMAN knows that the level 0 is not available.

Prior to 10g (or with compatibility < 10.0) [Oracle would do a level 0 when a level 1 was done without a level 0](http://www.pythian.com/news/287/level-1-incremental-backup-in-oracle-10g/).  Since you are on 11g, I would expect your compatibility to be >=10.0, so RMAN ["copies all blocks that have been changed since the file was created"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmcncpt.htm#BRADV89498).  This behavior seems to have changed between versions and there is some [confusion as to what the current behavior is,](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2215369&tstart=0) but your findings are consistent with the documentation.

Comment: thank you for you responce. But the following sentence confuses me: "copies all blocks that have been changed since the file was created" Which file is mentioned? which file was created? Thank you

Comment: one more question: Do I need to indicate recovery windows in RMAN?

Comment: I believe "the file" is referring to the datafile.

Comment: Retention policy information can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmcncpt.htm#i1008093